# PHPExel Create XLS overload ram

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to know If there is a way to reduce use of memory when create a XLS with PHPEXEL. There are like 15000 rows for these file.

I have This Script:

```
    $payroll_incomes = $payroll_incomes->execute(null, Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($payroll_incomes[0], null, 'A1');

// Rename worksheet

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('INGRESOS');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);



// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Ingresos.xls"');

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');



$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save('php://output')
```

When I run this script I get this message

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20 bytes) in /var/www/payroll/plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 962
```

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I have added this lines of code:

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;

$cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '10KB');

PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);



$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

So It's work exelent :)

Comment: Two options: 1. Run fewer lines through. Can it be done in several, smaller batches? 2. Contact the PHPExcel devs.

Comment: @Sammitch how I can do a smaller batches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by looking at the section of the PHPExcel documentation that talks about Cell Cacheing: this is a way of reducing the memory requirements of PHPExcel when working with larger spreadsheets, and was implemented for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I have Updated My Question, so I'm getting the same results. :(

Comment: Cell caching reduces memory usage, it doesn't eliminate it... you need to find the right caching method and the right PHP memory limits to work with your file sizes - cell caching just provides the mechanism and options to lower the memory requirements

Comment: $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB'); means that PHPExcel will use a 8MB of memory for cell caching before it starts to use temporary disk space; increasing that 8MB to 100MB will force PHPExcel to use __more__ memory, not less

Comment: I set $cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '10KB'); and it works!! Thanks!!